# I2S on imx7d: can not open pcm_out driver

Tags: audio, android-things

I'm a little desperate.

I2S seems not to work.

If I try to play a sound with audioTrack. In the raspberry pi 3 it works without problems, but if I execute it in imx7d it gives me the following error:

- audio_hw_primary: card 0, port 0 device 0x1000000
- audio_hw_primary: rate 48000, channel 2 period_size 0xc0
- audio_hw_primary: can not open pcm_out driver 0: can not set hw params: Invalid argument

The same thing happens with an i2s microphone

This is the code:

```
    final AudioDeviceInfo audioOuputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUS);

    int mBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        AudioFormat audioOutputFormat = new AudioFormat.Builder()
                .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
                .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                .setSampleRate(44100)
                .build();

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack.Builder()
                .setAudioFormat(audioOutputFormat)
                .setBufferSizeInBytes(mBufferSize * 2)
                .setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM)
                .build();

        audioTrack.setPreferredDevice(audioOuputDevice);
        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(44100);
        audioTrack.setVolume(AudioTrack.getMaxVolume());
```

Comment: Are you checking the pinouts of the imx7 to make sure you're connecting it correctly?

Comment: It is not about pins connections:

https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d

It doesn't matter, connected or unconnected. 

Same Result.